# diffrence between use of function instrrev() and instr()

Tags: excel, vba

I need a suggestion about Instr function, please find below code

```
strSearch = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
```

and another code is -

```
strSearch = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, (Instr(1,ActiveWorkbook.Name,".",vbTextCompare)-1)
```

Both code is giving same result as I want to print ActiveWorkbook name. Pls suggest me what is the difference between both code & which is better to use.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you search google/MSDN?

Comment: `Instr` return the position of the string searhed from the start, `InstrRev` returns the result the position from the end of the string.

Comment: [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1.aspx)  returns the position of the first occurence of the substring searched from the start (i.e. left-to-right); [InStrRev function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2ekk41a%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) also returns the position of the substring from the start (i.e. left-to-right) but the search looks from right-to-left. With InstrRev, you would find the position of the last occurrence first. If you only have one occurrence then both will return the same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the functions searches dot (here) as delimiter of file name & file extension. One search from begin of string, and another - from the end. Both returns position of founded substring from begin of string. And you just lucky that your file has no dot in its name :)
.